# Deciding in controller whether view should be rendered in parent or the referred fancybox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox-2

In an application I regularly open a fancybox to create an object. For example creating a new project would hit `new` action in `projects_controller`, and render the corresponding `new` view in a fancybox.

In the view a form is rendered and the `target` of the form is set to `'_parent'`, so that on create the page is redirected to parent of the fancebox. Eg:

```
= simple_form_for Project.new, html: { target: '_parent' }
```

The create action in the controller has specific business logic that decides if the object can be created with the given input or not, and if it cannot the new action should be rendered again, pre-filled with the initially typed in information. The problem with this is that the new action is rendered in the parent view and not the fancybox.

Is there a way do control from the controller where a view should be rendered? Is this a feature present in fancybox?

**Update:**
I used this
http://jonkinney.com/blog/2012/07/08/breaking-out-of-an-iframe-from-a-rails-controller/ to work around the problem. To make this work I had to remove the target from the form. (and thereby assume that the create would fail and it has to render new in the fancybox again). If it then actually succeeded i would use an equivalent to the `breakout_path` mentioned in the article. This works but feels really hacky in a wrong way.

Comment: When you say "In the view a form is rendered and the target of the form is set to '_parent'", where is it set to '_parent'?  Isn't it just a case of making this conditional to whether the save was successful?

Comment: The logic happens in the create action where the __new__ form only should be rendered again if for some reason it could not be created. The problem is basically that i don't know if the form is valid before it is submitted, and therefore cannot decide where to redirect/render with the target before the create action in the controller.